# Presenting Alerts on Specific View Controllers in Controller Stack | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently using a library to present a `Detail View Controller` on top of my `Main View Controller` as soon as the `Main` is loaded. The library is meant to replicate how bottom sheet is always displayed in the Apple Maps app.

I noticed that because the library is using present and overlaying the `Main View Controller` any Alert View is also being displayed in the `Detail View Controller` instead of `Main View Controller` even when its called in `Main View Controller`.

Is there a way to specifically present an alert message on a specific view controller in a stack?

**How I am presenting the `Detail View Controller`:**

```
let bottomSheetVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Details") as! DetailsVC
        animator = DraggableTransitionDelegate(viewControllerToPresent: bottomSheetVC, presentingViewController: self)
        bottomSheetVC.transitioningDelegate = animator
        bottomSheetVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

        present(bottomSheetVC, animated: true) {
            print("completed Presentation")
        }
```

**What I am currently doing to display the view controller in `Main View Controller`:**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What's your name?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { textField in
    textField.placeholder = "Input your name here..."
})

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in

    if let name = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
        print("Your name: \(name)")
    }
}))

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting the alert on bottom sheet vc

```
// inside main vc save a reference to the bottom sheet

let bottomSheetVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Details") as! DetailsVC
        animator = DraggableTransitionDelegate(viewControllerToPresent: bottomSheetVC, presentingViewController: self)
        bottomSheetVC.transitioningDelegate = animator
        bottomSheetVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

        present(bottomSheetVC, animated: true) {
            print("completed Presentation")
        }

//  save it to a property
self.bottomSheetVC = bottomSheetVC
```

and then use that reference to present it

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What's your name?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { textField in
    textField.placeholder = "Input your name here..."
})

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in

    if let name = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
        print("Your name: \(name)")
    }
}))

//  present it with this vc since it's on top
self.bottomSheetVC?.present(alert, animated: true)

See if that works.
```